# Getting ConsumeContext not available when using MassTransit and Automatonymous Publish after previously using RaiseEvent

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit, automatonymous

If we set up a Saga and immediately `Publish(context => ...)` then a message successfully hits the bus.

If however, we have something like

```
Initially(
  When(SomeCommand)
     .Then(context => { context.Instance.SomeField = 5 })
     .TransitionTo(SomeState)
     .Then(context => this.RaiseEvent(context.Instance, SomeEvent)));

During(SomeState,
  When(SomeEvent)
     // ConsumeContext is not available here
     .Publish(context => new SomeEventClass
        {
           Foo = context.Instance.SomeField
        })
     .Finalize());
```

The machine also never transitions to the Final state presumably because of the exception locating a ConsumeContext.

We have seen some references to passing a `ConsumeContext` as a parameter in `Publish()` however it's unclear as to which context this needs (Intellisense just makes reference to context1, context2, context3, etc).

Is there a way to use `Publish()` after `RaiseEvent()` has already been called? If not, is there a way to publish an event using some other mechanism?

MassTransit version is 5.1.5 and Automatonymous is 4.1.2

---

**EDIT** Based on Chris Patterson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149526#53154225) we have tried adding the below outside of any `Initially` or `During`

```
WhenEnter(NewState, state => state.Publish(context => 
    new EventClass { Foo = context.Instance.Foo }
  )
  .Finalize();
```

However it still doesn't publish anything and the state never transitions to `Final`. If we add a `Then` it also never hits this code block. There don't seem to be any exceptions occurring. We also tried using `When(SomeState.Enter)` and it also doesn't work.

Side question as maybe this will help with my understanding of why `Publish` and `RaiseEvent` don't seem to play nicely together - why does `Publish` need the `ConsumeContext`? Is it to locate the bus and bindings?

Comment: Before trying to look at this, could clarify what is the reason to raise an internal event after transitioning to the next state, which publishes one message and finalizes? Can't you publish and finalize right in that step before?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev this is a massive simplification. The scenario is that we have a whole lot of events and actions that have to happen and we want to be able to retry at a particular state. Only when all the internal events have happened do we want to publish the final message. Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: We stuff like this too but we always use messages...

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev could you give an example? None of the services being co-ordinated publish messages and there's a lot of overhead (message classes, consumer classes) if we go down the route of using messages and not internal events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be using this:

```
.Then(context => context.Raise(SomeEvent))
```

instead of this:

```
.Then(context => this.RaiseEvent(context.Instance, SomeEvent))
```

It kinda makes sense now - the latter (as mentioned by Chris Patterson) creates a new `EventContext` while the former uses the given `context`. We didn't know that `Raise` was a method available on the passed in `context`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add

```
When(SomeState.Enter)
```

to your `Initially` section, and it will use the existing context. By creating a new `EventContext` with `RaiseEvent`, you aren't retaining the `ConsumeContext`.

You could also add `WhenEnter(SomeState)` outside of any `Initially` or `During` block.

Comment: we tried both and neither seems to work. See my edit above.